# How to Prove Periodic Solution of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good evening! Help me, please, to prove that any solution of equation $$(x')' + x^3 = 0$$ is periodic function. I tried to use $x = x'z$ way, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: @Moo, yes, the second derivative

Answer (score 2):

The equation is conservative. Given any solution $x$, let's define a quantity $$Q=\frac 12(x')^2 + \frac14 x^4.$$
Now let's look at how it changes in time $$Q'=x'(x'' + x^3)=0.$$
The quantity is therefore constant in time, and so every solution lies on a level set of that function. If you look at the level sets in phase space, you see that they make closed ellipsoids (not sure if the 4th power is still called an ellipse or not, but it doesn't much matter, it's closed and ellipse-like), and are therefore periodic.

Comment: Can you prove it without so difficult ways? I'm not aware of phase space. This problem has to have a simple solution...

Comment: I can't do it in a simpler way. I'm not sure there is one.

Comment: for example, we can use t = e^k and x = u * e^(-k). Then, we'll have (u')' + u^3 + 2u - 3y' = 0

Comment: @MysterX You should specify what you have learned prior to this question so that people could provide the ''appropriate answer'', given what you know.